# How do you revert the control keys back to "normal" operation?

Tags: keyboard-layout

Dell desktop, Logitech wireless keyboard, Ubuntu 11.10.

Yesterday my right and left control keys got (re/un)mapped, but I'm not sure by what.  Now, whenever I press either one, a red "pulsating" red circle flashes under the pointer and then returns to normal.  In Ubuntu this is the only sign that something has changed.  However, in Virtualbox with a Windows guest, nothing that uses the control key will work.  I'm not sure what changed it or where to look for how to change it back.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me. Although I didn't change anything somehow my mouse settings changed.

You have to go to System Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad -> uncheck **Show position of pointer when the control key is pressed**. That should do it.

Comment: unfortunately in 13.04 that flashing pointer option is no longer available in the Trackpad/Mouse settings (or I'm bling and can't find it). so my setting is permanently turned on until I can find it in gconf.